# Interesting result on differential equations : proof that a function nullify itself a infinity times

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have an amazing exercice to do, and I share it with you. I have one answer, but I understand it only partially, and it sets an intermediary function, that makes the proof  fuzzy.

> Let $ q : \mathbb R^*_+ \rightarrow \mathbb R^*_+ $, such that
>   $\int^{+\infty}_1 q(t) \, dt = + \infty $
>
> Show that the solutions of this differential equation, nullify
>   themselves infinity times:
>
> $$y''(x) + q(x) y(x) = 0$$

---

P.S. maybe the expression to nullify themselves infinity times is not english... the idea is that : $| \{x\in \mathbb R\mid f(x)=0\}| =\infty$

---

My attempt :

I tackle the problem in this way :
I assume by absurdo that the solution of the differential equation vanishes only a finite times. Thus, since one point (called $a$), the solution is of constant sign. WLOG the solution is positive since one point. 
Then we set the function : $$z(x) = - \frac {y'(x)}{y(x)} $$
we have that : $$ z'(x) = q(x) + z^2(x)$$
So $$ \forall x > a, z(x) = z(a) + \int_a^x z'(t) dt \geq z(a) + \int_a^x q(t) dt > + \infty$$
So $$ \exists b > a, z(b) > 0 $$ 
Thus finally : $$y'(b) = y(b) z(b) < 0.$$

Comment: that's true... I'm sorry... But that was the idea :) Do you have any idea how to write it mathematically?

Comment: Could you share what you already tried?

Comment: `$| \{x\in \Bbb R\mid f(x)=0\}| =\infty$`, that is $| \{x\in \Bbb R\mid f(x)=0\}|=\infty$

Comment: done @rafa11111

Comment: I think you didn't get what @ArnaudMortier meant. You should write something like $\exists x \ | \ y(x)=0 \ \  \mathrm{and} \ \ \forall x \ \exists x'>x \ | \ y(x') = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint.

Assuming $f(x) \in C^1$
$$
y''y'+f(x)y y' = 0\Rightarrow \frac{d}{dx}(y')^2+f(x)\frac{d}{dx}y^2 = 0
$$

but

$$
f(x)\frac{d}{dx}(y^2) = \frac{d}{dx}\left(f(x)y^2\right)-y^2 f'(x)
$$

so

$$
(y')^2+ f(x)y^2 = \int y^2 f'(x)
$$

Here $f(x) \ge 0$ then

$$
(y')^2+ f(x)y^2 \gt 0
$$

because

$$
\int f dx \rightarrow \infty
$$

then the orbits in the phase plane are typical of a periodic function etc.

Comment: can you precise the last argument please? I'm sure it can be really interesting to know the end of your proof. I stopped when you said :  $$ y'^2 + q y^2 > 0 $$

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track!

Just change $z(a) + \int_a^x q(t) dt > + \infty$ to $z(a) + \int_a^x q(t) dt \xrightarrow [x \to +\infty]{} + \infty$ because $\int_a^x q(t) dt$ is finite.
From this, obtain $\exists b > a, z(b) > 0$ (as you've done) and $$y'(b) = -y(b) z(b) < 0.$$Now, since $y''(x)=-q(x)y(x) \le 0$ for all $x > a$, $y'(x)$ is non-increasing and $y'(x) \le y'(b)$ for all $x \ge b$. Thus, $$\forall x \ge b,\; y(x)=y(b)+\int_b^x y'(t) dt \le y(b) + \int_b^x y'(b) dt = y(b) + (x-b)y'(b),$$ and taking $x > b - \frac {y(b)}{y'(b)}$, we get $y(x) < 0$, a contradiction.

Comment: do you have a graphic intuition of all of those things ? wy do we set the function z etc...

Comment: Well, the last part can be illustrated by bounding the function's $y(x)$ graph by the tangent at the point $(b, y(b))$. Since $y'(b) < 0$, the tangent has a negative slope and thus will eventually intersect the x-axis at some point. Setting $z(x) = - \frac {y'(x)}{y(x)}$ is just a [known substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riccati_equation#Reduction_to_a_second_order_linear_equation) to switch between a second order linear ordinary differential equation and a Riccati equation.

Comment: John, thank you for the explaination. Can you tell one more thing? You speak about the known substitution ( i ve discovered it, really interesting), but here we do not have a Ricatti equation. So why do you think about it?

Comment: In truth, it's you who first talked about $z'(x) = q(x) + z^2(x)$, not me. This is a Riccati equation. The substitution $z(x) = - \frac {y'(x)}{y(x)}$ is two-way: when we need to obtain a linear equation from quadratic Riccati equation, we use it. When we need to reduce the order  sacrificing the linearity, as in this case, we can use it too.